# Pointer to member function of base class error

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Can some one please help me identify where i am going wrong? I am trying to use function pointers to a base class function

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments    on the line number 30 ie *(app)()

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int a(){
        printf("A");
        return 0;
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    int b(){
        printf("B");
        return 0;
    }
};

class C : public B{
public:
    int(C::*app)();
    int c(){
        app =&C::a;
        printf("%s",typeid(app).name());
        *(app)();
        printf("C");
        return 0;
    }
};
int main(){
    C *obj = new C();
    obj->c();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Try `(this->*app)();`

Comment: Why are you trying to use a pointer to the base class function? Is there any particular reason you can't just call `A::a();`?

Comment: @maditya just using this program to get some concepts clear

Answer (score 3):

You have to use .* or ->* while invoking pointers to member functions

```
    class C : public B{
    public:
        int(C::*app)();
        int c(){
            app =&C::a;
            printf("%s",typeid(app).name());
            (this->*app)(); // use ->* operator within ()
            printf("C");
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointers to members must always be used in combination with a pointer/reference to object. You probably meant to write this:

```
(this->*app)();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx

> The binary operator –>* combines its first operand, which must be a
>   pointer to an object of class type, with its second operand, which
>   must be a pointer-to-member type.

So this will solve your problem:

```
class C : public B {
    public:
        int(C::*app)();

        int c() {
            app = &C::a;
            printf("%s", typeid(app).name());
            (this->*app)();
            printf("C");
            return 0;
        }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, by the time I had searched & posted answer, other people were already quicker than me. I must know I am in the world of stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch the problem you're really trying to solve is "How do I call a base class function from the derived class?" If that's the case, the answer is:

```
int c(){
    app =&C::a;
    printf("%s",typeid(app).name());
    A::a(); //A:: scopes the function that's being called
    printf("C");
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int c(){
    app =&C::a;
    printf("%s",typeid(app).name());
    this->a();
    printf("C");
    return 0;
}
```